# Visual studio не показывает ошибки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

После git clone VS ни как не помогает с отступами и не показывает ошибки в проекте, даже если запятую убрать например ИДЕ будет плевать. Пробовал менять на текущий документ или проект, но ничего не работает.

Comment: Файл .editorconfig наличествует?

Comment: Из-за него может пропасть поиск ошибок?